# Observer not picked up on live server

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I have been writing an extension to carry out a SOAP API request. This works locally fine, however when on the live server my observer isnt picked up and therefore not fired.

I have read up and thought it could be an issue with letter cases but i really can't spot it.

Below is my `config.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Webtise_ExperianCheck>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Webtise_ExperianCheck>
  </modules>
<global>

    <blocks>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <customer_edit_tab_view_orders>Webtise_ExperianCheck_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tab_View_Orders</customer_edit_tab_view_orders>
                <customer_edit_tab_orders>Webtise_ExperianCheck_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tab_Orders</customer_edit_tab_orders>
                <sales_order_grid>Webtise_ExperianCheck_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid</sales_order_grid>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>

    <models>
        <experiancheck>
            <class>Webtise_ExperianCheck_Model</class>
        </experiancheck>
    </models>

    <events>
        <sales_order_place_after>
            <observers>
                <experiancheck>
                    <class>webtise_experiancheck/observer</class>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <method>sendExperian</method>
                </experiancheck>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_place_after>
    </events>

    <resources>
        <experian_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Webtise_ExperianCheck</module>
                <class>Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </experian_setup>
        <experian_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </experian_write>
        <experian_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </experian_read>
    </resources>

    <template>
        <email>
            <experian_tpl module="Webtise_ExperianCheck">
                <label>Experian Check Result</label>
                <file>experian_result.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </experian_tpl>
        </email>
    </template>

</global>


<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <experiancheck>
                <file>webtise/experian.xml</file>
            </experiancheck>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>

</config>
```

Any help would be appreciated. My `Observer.php` file is in the following directory:
**app/code/local/Webtise/ExperianCheck/Model/Observer.php**

`config.xml`:
**app/code/local/Webtise/ExperianCheck/etc/config.xml**

Local machine is Macbookpro. Server Linux.

Comment: Your module/class should be `experiancheck/observer`

Comment: Hi @Rabee, cheers for the comment, ive just tried this and im afraid it didnt work either. Any other ideas?

Comment: Flushed cache after ?

Comment: Yep flushed the cache.

Comment: if your local machine is on Windows and the live env is on linux, be careful at case sensitivity of the file names.

Comment: Hi Marius, i thought this myself, my local machine is a Macbook Pro, im going to try changing the structure to Webtise/Experiancheck to see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out it was down to case sensitivity on my Macbook, got it to work eventually. Thanks to Marius and Rabee for the comments, I know for future reference to always bare in mind case sensitivity when creating modules!